# minikube kube-dns addon not working? Can't enable it

Tags: minikube

I think this relates to https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2302

This is what I've done:

- I started minikube (just as it is, no further settings).
- I enabled the kube-dns addon.
- I did minikube stop && minikube delete.
- I upgrade k8s to v1.10.0 and started minikube again.

Addon is still enabled but no pods are there. I'm unable to enable the addon again.

```
$ kubectl get po --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                                                  READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default       elasticsearch-elasticsearch-client-79ddfc66f5-rlx9c   0/1       Running   8          23m
default       elasticsearch-elasticsearch-data-0                    1/1       Running   0          23m
default       elasticsearch-elasticsearch-master-0                  1/1       Running   0          23m
default       postgres-postgresql-55bf4844b-ttkbf                   1/1       Running   0          23m
kube-system   kube-addon-manager-minikube                           1/1       Running   0          39m
kube-system   tiller-deploy-f9b8476d-qdsz6                          1/1       Running   0          39m
```

And this is the addons list output

```
$ minikube addons list
- addon-manager: enabled
- coredns: disabled
- dashboard: enabled
- default-storageclass: enabled
- efk: disabled
- freshpod: disabled
- heapster: disabled
- ingress: enabled
- kube-dns: enabled
- registry: disabled
- registry-creds: disabled
- storage-provisioner: enabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2302#issuecomment-394345502) provided by [AmazingTurtle](https://github.com/AmazingTurtle):

I enabled DNS by creating these [three](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/tree/v0.30.0/deploy/addons/kube-dns) manifests manually

- [kube-dns-cm.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/77942bbf94b595943c8a29bb15b63d7326ef044f/deploy/addons/kube-dns/kube-dns-cm.yaml)
- [kube-dns-controller.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/77942bbf94b595943c8a29bb15b63d7326ef044f/deploy/addons/kube-dns/kube-dns-controller.yaml)
- [kube-dns-svc.yaml](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/77942bbf94b595943c8a29bb15b63d7326ef044f/deploy/addons/kube-dns/kube-dns-svc.yaml)

Just did kubectl apply -f 
for all the three items

**Update:**

The mentioned files was deleted by the [PR#3332](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/3332/) from the master branch, so I've changed the links to the last commit that contains them.

Comment: those links 404 now

Comment: I've fixed the links.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a VirtualBox issue. I found this on [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1451); looks like an update broke it.

```
# Run this if you can't reach the internet from a minikube pod.
# This is most likely a VirtualBox issue.
# https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/1451

minikube stop
VBoxManage modifyvm "minikube" --natdnshostresolver1 on
minikube start
```

I'm running `Minikube version: v0.34.1`.